# Orthogonal projector = I?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, projection

I was reading a paper and going through the definition part.[image]

For first paragraph, since B is a matrix with orthonormal columns, wouldnt $BB^{T} = I_{d\times d}$ ?

For second paragraph, note that the span{$v_{i} |  i\in [k]$} refer to the span of the k right singular vectors of A corresponding to highest k singluar value. And so how does it make sense of 'projecting the rows onto some span of some span of right singular vectors (of A)"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\beta$ is an orthonormal basis of $\operatorname{im}\Pi$ (the image/column space of $\Pi$), not of the whole space. Therefore $B$ is actually an $n\times d$ matrix and $BB^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with generally non-trivial $\ker$. An equivalent formulation of the property would be that an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is on orthogonal projector if and only if $A^2=A$ and $\ker A\perp \operatorname{im}A$.

Comment: You can  identify the orthogonal projectors with vector subspaces by means of the image map $$\{\operatorname{orthogonal projectors}\}\to \{\text{vector subspaces}\}\\ \Pi\mapsto \operatorname{im}\Pi$$ The inverse of that map is the map that assigns to a vector subspace $W$ the linear map that is the identity on $W$ and zero on $W^\perp$.